sudo user input sanitize, to avoid error "bash: Invalid option" or "sh: Invalid option"
I'm using sudo from bash to execute an arbitrary wild command as a specific user.
This works perfectly in general cases:
sudo --login --user=maria -- "$COMMAND"

For example, this calls the command /bin/whoami perfectly:
sudo --login --user=maria -- "whoami"
maria

But, please pretend that you have a command called /bin/-something-.
This, instead, does not work:
sudo --login --user=maria -- "-do-things-"
-sh: 0: Illegal option -d

What's going on here? Why is my argument confused as shell option?
Troubleshooting
I understand that -do-things- is confused like a shell option -d (the internal shell executed by sudo) so, something is probably not sanitizing correctly the input.
Accordingly to the sudo manual page:

sudo supports -- to separate sudo options from the command (so I'm already using it)

Relevant sudo --login manual page section:

If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell as a simple command using the -c option.  The command and any args are concatenated, separated by spaces

So, sudo --login COMMAND runs a $SHELL -c 'COMMAND' internally.
So as default in my environment (Debian) this runs bash -c. So I've explored the bash manual page to understand the -c. Relevant part:

-c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.

So, I tried various nonsense attempts, also with double escaping using -- (one for sudo, and one for sh) without success, all giving the same error of illegal option error:
COMMAND="-do-things-"
sudo --login --user=maria -- "$COMMAND"
sudo --login --user=maria -- -- "$COMMAND"
sudo --login --user=maria -- "-- $COMMAND"

→ /bin/bash: --: invalid option
I've also tried different shells, like /bin/sh, with the same error:
export SHELL=/bin/sh
COMMAND="-do-something"
sudo --shell --user=maria -- "$COMMAND"
sudo --shell --user=maria -- -- "$COMMAND"
sudo --shell --user=maria -- "-- $COMMAND"

→ /bin/sh: 0: Illegal option --
Additional Notes
Arrived to this point, premising that I think that sudo is trying to do this (whatever the shell):
bash -c -do-things-
sh   -c -do-things-

And premising that these works:
bash -c -- -do-things-
sh   -c -- -do-things-

There is a possibility that I've found a small sudo bug, since it's probably missing the internal escape -- (or the possibility to use it) to separate shell options from the user provided command.
Anyway I cannot proof that right now since I'm not completely familiar with the sudo codebase.
https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo
Thanks for any troubleshooting tip, and eventually to understand how to sanitize user input correctly in this simple wrapper.

I've done my best to provided a super-minimal example. Available for clarifications

(1) You call sudo --login --user=maria -- "$COMMAND" the "minimal implementation" of run.sh. It is too minimal; I mean it is not complete. What is the shebang? How is $COMMAND derived from $1 or $@? (2) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484363/108618

Thanks @KamilMaciorowski - I've updated the question mentioning that I'm using Bash but I can reproduce in any shell, with export SHELL=/bin/sh etc.

Challenge accepted! :)
Of course, there are probably plenty other ways than mine to resolve your issue.

So i have this -weird- file (located in /home/radis/).

containing this:
#!/bin/bash
id
pwd


I want to make it available in /bin/ with a symbolic link as to
match your situation

(as root).
ln -s /home/radis/-weird- /bin/-weird-


At this point, the following commands works in a bash shell (shell:~#).

(in root as well as in user radis)
-weird-
/home/radis/./-weird-
/bin/./-weird-
bash -c ./-weird-
bash -c -- -weird-


This works

(full situation, as root)
COMMAND="-weird-" 
COMMAND_SAN=$(echo $COMMAND |sed 's/-/\\-/g')

sudo --login --user=radis bash -c -- "$COMMAND"
sudo --login --user=radis bash -c "$COMMAND_SAN"

#this also works (alternate ways when using relative filepaths)
sudo --login --user=radis bash -c -- "./$COMMAND"
sudo --login --user=radis bash -c "./$COMMAND"

Some explanations
Key point N°1: To make sudo work, you do not need to enclose your entire command-line in double quotes (it is not necessary).
Key point N°2: recalling bash with '-c' at the start of your sudo command-line help prevent interpreting '-' as arguments.
Key point N°3: Utilizing 'bash -c' alongside with characters escaping (COMMAND_SAN) ensures that dashes are always treated as characters, not arguments.
Key point N°4: When executing a script by providing its full or relative path, using the relative path indicator './' allows for interpreting dashes as characters rather than arguments in filenames (example: /home/radis/./-weird-).
Hope it helps.
